# Visual Studio Code 'Setting Sync from Microsoft' vs. 'Setting Sync from Shan Khan'

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried to sync my visual studio code settings / extensions. Many sync steps I did manual.

I found then these both tools

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync

The first is from Microsoft and integrated (out of the box) in VScode. The second one is a high rated extension.

When I want to start a sync where should I start? Is there a recommended way? I cannot see many differences for the both tools.

My environment Win 10 with VScode and additional two times WSL2 Alpine and Ubuntu each with vscode.

Answer (score 15):

Summary:  Use VS Code's built-in Setting Sync for most cases.  Use Khan's Setting Sync extension if you require multiple profiles (ie multiple settings) or you are running open source version of VS Code (such as VSCodium).

Before the official VS Code's version was released, the most popular way to sync VS Code settings across computers (and across platforms like Windows, Mac and Linux) was possible with Shan Khan's [Settings Sync - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync).  This extension works really well, but it requires the users to set up their Github as it saves the settings to their private Gist.

VS Code had recently released its own Settings Sync, which unfortunately uses the same name as the extension, causing some confusion amongst the users.  The built-in sync requires account in MS or Github.  According to the VS Code documentation, it is completely different from Khan's Settings Sync extension. Now that the VS Code has introduced the feature of syncing, the writing might be on the wall for the extension.  However, the extension has other features that is not available in the VS Code, so I think it will continue to be used and updated.

Khan's Settings Sync extension might be preferrable over the VS Code's built-in sync for some cases.  Khan's Setting Sync can have multiple profile.  Also OSS version of VS Code such as [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com/) doesn't include this feature, so the extension might be the only way to have this feature.  Also, it is sometimes useful to be able to see different versions of your settings in Github Gist, as it maintains versioning.  Finally, Khan's Settings Sync is also available for Azure Data Studio, which is based on VSCode.

Comment: The other major benefit is that the Settings Sync extension allows you to specify settings per platform (i.e., different values for macOS and Windows for the same setting). Very useful if you work cross-platform. https://zellwk.com/blog/sync-mac-windows-vscode/

Comment: Does anyone know where the integrated Settings Sync saves the settings on GitHub exactly ? It says all is synced OK but I can't find anything on Github so I'm getting paranoid.

Comment: @dee My guess is that the integrated settings sync doesn't use github gist to store the sync data.  It uses Github account only for user authentication.  My guess is that actual sync data would be stored by Microsoft and is not meant for viewing.

Comment: @dee It uses a github gist rather than a repository.

Comment: VSCode added multiple profiles for sync-settings. It's there in `1.8.2` right now.

Answer (score 5):

the newest vscode update has the additional settings in which you can turn on the settings sync. Just go to file -> preferences -> settings sync. I used to use the extensions for my settings sync but now i don't use it anymore

Comment: Thanks Owen. Did you find any reason to stick to the extension? e.g. some features are missing? When I get it right the internal Sync is using "a cloud" and not anymore "github gist" for sync purpose. I am afraid, when the internal sync feature will be removed or become a payed feature that I do not have a "access point", like github.

Comment: I personally don't use the xtension because it might slow down the startup of my vscode and sometimes i hate it when the vscode autoupdates the changes, it disrupt my workflow.

Comment: I would like to know if the highly rated extension is safe to have :) When I tried to use it I received the following message: "A third-party OAuth application (Settings Sync) with gist and read:user scopes was recently authorized to access your account." The "third party" part made me think twice and I just went along the internal sync feature, which I found to be practically the same in terms of settings.

Comment: Thirdparty in this case just means that something other than vs code and yourself.. It doesn't mean that it's a terrorist XD @brijabasi

Comment: @OwenValentinus I only _see _settings sync is on__ on the preferences not _which_ account is used to sync the settings to.